# Error during RTSP streaming using gstreamer

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer, rtsp

I'm using gstreamer to do RTSP streaming. 
To achieve that I downloaded the gst-rtsp-server setup from https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/src/gst-rtsp-server/ . I compiled the code successfully. I could start the gstreamer rtsp server using (server side code )

**./test-launch "(videotestsrc ! x264enc ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96)"**

After this server starts listening at port 8554

At the receiver side (client) , to play the streamed video I'm using

**gst-launch-1.0 -v rtspsrc location=rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test**

But I'm getting following error at server side  :

```
    ** Message: state PLAYING media 0xb04160
    ** Message: 0xb04160: got message type new-clock
    0:00:04.375120259 17746       0xa74b00 WARN                     bin gstbin.c:2395:gst_bin_do_latency_func:<media-pipeline> did not really configure latency of 0:00:00.000000000

    ** Message: client 0x95d760: sent a message with cseq 4
    0:00:04.391459616 17746       0xa9f230 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:2625:gst_base_src_loop:<udpsrc0> error: Internal data flow error.
    0:00:04.391536109 17746       0xa9f230 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:2625:gst_base_src_loop:<udpsrc0> error: streaming task paused, reason not-linked (-1)

** (lt-test-launch:17746): WARNING **: 0xb04160: got error Internal data flow error. (gstbasesrc.c(2625): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:media-pipeline/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0:
streaming task paused, reason not-linked (-1))
RTSP request message 0xaa0888
```

Kindly tell me,  what  gstreamer elements has to be used at client side ?
**I could play the streaming video successfully using VLC** (Open VLC -- > Media --> Open Network Streaming -- > RTSP://path.... )

Note: 
Im' using gstreamer-1.0
I'm using Ubuntu PC for client and server setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to run this with below command:

gst-launch-1.0 -v rtspsrc location=rtsp://127.0.0.1/test caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, payload=(int)96, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264" ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! autovideosink

Answer (score 0):

At server side you are encoding the data using x264enc, so at client side you have to decode it and then have to play it.

Try this pipeline, It will work

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v rtspsrc location=rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! xvimagesink
```